# Identify a deleted file from Repository with ANT build

Tags: svn, ant

I need to find a deleted file from the directory and need to delete the same file from server. Is it possible with ANT build to find the deleted file

Comment: Do `commit` you local working copy and later version will have file excluded..what else you need?

Comment: with ant build i'm deploying files to server. Once a file is deleted from local svn it needs to be deleted from server also.

Comment: Sounds like you're making a change in a subversion checkout? In that case commit the change and it'll be gone from the repository. On you're server there might be a second checkout, in which case you need to issue an update command to bring it back in sync with the repo.

Comment: But, server is not in subversion. It is a place in which file will be deployed.

Comment: Once developer commit changes to source file, files will be deployed to the server with CI setup (ANT build script)

Comment: `server is not in subversion`.....wait..what??? You delete all file in local and commit then all file in server will be deleted. You need to ask to your seniors and I am sure they will clarify your doubt of not using svn server..

Comment: My scope is when a file is deleted from subversion, ANT build triggers and nothing will transfer to the server as the files is deleted. the file remain in the server (My deployment is happening like when a change is made in svn files only updated files will be moved to the server. Likewise i want deleted files to be deleted form the server through ANT build)